# .Net Compact Framework console application - silent termination because of OutOfMemory

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, compact-framework, windows-ce

On a headless Windows CE 6.0 R3 device I am running a .Net CF 3.5 based console application. This console application, consisting of many DLLs, is all managed code. Also, it does not have any database functionality and ofcourse no Windows Forms controls.
After some random duration, ranging from about 12 hours to 48 hours, this application stops running and looks like it was silently terminated by the CF runtime. Following are the investigation results:

1. Remote debugging through VS2008 does not show any run-time exceptions. Even if in the Debug->Exceptions menu the 'Common Language Runtime exceptions'->'System' has 'Thrown' enabled.
2. The .Net CF Remote Performance Monitor, after the application termination, shows the below:
   [.Net CF RPM GC memory statisics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n15HX.png)
   A. Managed Bytes In Use After GC value does not go up and down drastically.
   B. Total Bytes In Use After GC shows a strange value.
3. Enabling Windows CE Error Reporting is of no help as dump files are not generated.
4. The only hint that can be got is when .Net CF Error Logging is enabled. After the silent application termination a file 'netcf_Error.log' is created and it normally contains a single word "**OutOfMemory**". This word sometimes appears only once or is repeated few times.

Iam guessing that the issue could be something to do with heap fragmentation and not memory leak because the application uses one-time allocated memory buffers for doing most of the work. So I need help in understanding:

1. Is this silent app termination behavior normal in the .Net CF 3.5 runtime?
2. How to get more details about this 'OutOfMemory' error?

Comment: You possibly have a memory leak. You should log the memory use periodcally to a file with some details of the code location where you issued the memory log. Windows CE will terminate applications if they do not react on WM_HIBERNATE which is send if program memory get's low. You may also monitor your application with perfmon (see details at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevenpr/2006/04/17/analyzing-device-application-performance-with-the-net-compact-framework-remote-performance-monitor/)

Comment: Thanks @josef. Have already used .Net CF RPM(perfmon) tool and as seen in the snapshot attached in my question above the 'Managed Bytes In Use After GC' almost remains constant(few hundred bytes up & down).

Comment: WM_HIBERNATE is a good pointer. How to catch WM_HIBERNATE/WM_CLOSE messages in a C# console application as I see that they are part of WindowsCE.Forms.MobileDevice?

Comment: WM_HIBERNATE is only send to Windows Message handlers. As perfmon does not show all memory, you might go with a memory logger that logs memory usage for all processes over the time. Managed Bytes usage seems not sufficiant here.